# Accessing arrays in runnable NullPointException

Tags: android

So I have 4 double arrays through which I am updating a calculation. These 4 double arrays update themselves when a person hits a button. st array for start time , et array for end time, quantity and alcoholcontent arrays. When I press Drink Beer the start time array is updated, quantity and alcoholcontent array is also updated. When I press Finish Beer end time array gets updated. The calculations are done in a Runnable. Thats all fine but the problem is this that when I press on Drink Beer button I get a NUllPOintexception. I am calling the Timer_Tick from a runonUIThread. Any suggestions ?

```
private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        calculateBAC();
    }

    private void calculateBAC() {
        int j=0;
        while(et[j]!=0 && j<19) {
        BAC=quantity[j]*alcoholcontent[j];
        BAC=BAC*100*1.055;
        if(gender=="female")
            BAC=BAC/(weight*0.55);
        else
            BAC=BAC/(weight*0.68);
        c=Calendar.getInstance();
        CurrentTime=c.getTimeInMillis();
        c.clear();
        CurrentTime=CurrentTime-st[j];
        CurrentTime=CurrentTime/(1000*360);
        BAC=BAC-(CurrentTime*0.015);
        TotalBAC=TotalBAC+BAC;
        tv1.setText(TotalBAC+"%");
            j++;    
        }   
    }
};
```

......

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.drinkbeer: 
      if(beerstart==0) {
        beerstart=1;
        Log.d("worked","this worked");
        c=Calendar.getInstance();
        st[i]=c.getTimeInMillis();
        st[i]=(st[i]*0.001)/360;
        c.clear();
        quantity[i]=12;
        alcoholcontent[i]=0.06;
        beer.setText("Finish beer");
        break;
     }
}
```

Errors:

```
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at     com.example.baccalculator.bloodlevelcalculator.onClick(bloodlevelcalculator.java:120)
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)    
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 04:57:27.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12740):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: I don't see where `st` is defined or instantiated.  (Also, `gender == "female"` will fail since you're comparing String with `==`.  Just a heads-up.)

Comment: Can you tell what is the line number 120 of your code. Which has been shown in exception trace. I can see possibly your beer is null

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your onClick call is conflicted with your calculateBAC execution, for they share variables which are not well synchronized.

Comment: line number 120 is st[i]=c.getTimeInMillis();

Comment: gender is a SharedPreference which I fetch during the start of the OnCreate() function. st is also initialized in the activity. st is a double array with 20 elements all initialized by default as zero. st changes when I click on a button named "Drink beer". As I keep on pressing Drink beer the elements of st update first time click st[0] updates, second time click st[1] updates etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since

> line number 120 is st[i]=c.getTimeInMillis();

to me the only possible culprit is st[i]. How you are getting i? And who is synchronizing the access of a particular index of st?